# Debug help (keeps showing NaN)

Tags: javascript, nan

Please help me debug my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Miles to Kilometers Conveter</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
/* Defining Table: Program to convert miles to kilometers.
 * Input: Miles
 * Processing: How many kilometers in a amount of miles inputed
 * Output: output total kilometers
 */
     function milesToKilo(){
         var miles= getElementByID=("milesinput");
         var kilo=1.60934;
         var k= parseFloat(kilo);
         var total= miles*k;
        document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = total;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Miles to Kilometers Converter</h2>
  How many Miles?<input type="text" id="milesinput">
  <button type="button" onclick="milesToKilo()">Convert</button>
  <div id='outputDiv'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Jice! Your question set apart; you should learn how to indent and format your code! It will help you debug some errors in the future, and it helps other developers to read it too. As a beginner, it may seem a hassle, but it's worth the effort. I bet the people are downvoting your question because of that. Here is a nice tool that will do the work for you: http://jsbeautifier.org/, but you should do it has you write code

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, you needed to get a value of the element and parse an int from it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/NOYYKx0bYqJ2QJ21prUc?p=preview

```
function milesToKilo(){ 
  var miles = parseInt(document.getElementById("milesinput").value); 
  var kilo =1.60934; 
  var k = parseFloat(kilo); 
  var total= miles*k; 
  document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = total; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var miles = getElementById=("milesinput")` should be `var miles = getElementById("milesinput")`: Note the lack of `=` between `getElementById` and `(`. Besides that...

`miles` is being assigned the value of `getElementById("milesinput")`, which is an HTML `element` -- that's a particular *kind* of variable JavaScript, and is not a `number`.

An `element` of this type has the `value` property. You can access it with `miles.value`, but it is a `string` type. You'll need to convert it to a number like so:

`var total = parseFloat(miles.value) * k`

Comment: Wow thank you, I am brand new to programming. I did not expect such nice answers.

Comment: You're welcome and good luck (: